# Javascript function is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a function which is not working is expected.

The problem is that, I have set

`if (Trim(ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText) != 0)` then it should go inside and run another function, which is not going currently when my `if (Trim(ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText) != 0)` == `1`.

The debugger just throws me out of the parent function.
 I want that to run when value is other than `0`

Below is my js function

```
function getCounterForCheck() {
        StrPriFnName = "getCounterForCheckInward(" + document.getElementById('TxtInwardNo').value + ")";
        var ObjPriXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        ObjPriXMLHTTP.open("GET", "FrmInwardXMLHTTP.aspx?para=" + StrPriFnName, false);
        ObjPriXMLHTTP.send("");

        if (Trim(ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText) != 0) {

            function getOtherDBInward() {
                StrPriFnName = "FunGetOTHERDBInward(" + document.getElementById('TxtInwardNo').value + ")";
                var ObjPriXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                ObjPriXMLHTTP.open("GET", "FrmInwardXMLHTTP.aspx?para=" + StrPriFnName, false);
                ObjPriXMLHTTP.send("");

                if (Trim(ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText) != "") {
                    var StrPriData = ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText.split('~');
                    document.getElementById('HidRefMkey').value = StrPriData[0];
                    document.getElementById('TxtDeliveredBy').value = StrPriData[1];
                    document.getElementById('cmbRecdDept').value = StrPriData[2];
                    FunEmpFillDept();
                    document.getElementById('cmbRecdEmp').value = StrPriData[3];
                    document.getElementById('HidCurrentEmp').value = StrPriData[3];
                    document.getElementById('Txt_RefBillNo').value = StrPriData[6];
                    igdrp_getComboById("DtmInfRef_DocDate").setValue(Trim(StrPriData[7]));
                    igedit_getById("TxtWN_Billamt").setValue(StrPriData[8]);
                    document.getElementById('TxtRemarks').value = StrPriData[9];
                    document.getElementById('TxtPartyName').value = StrPriData[10];
                }

                else {
                    alert("ERROR: Document does not exist");
                    //alert("ERROR: Document does not exist and status also");
                    document.getElementById('TxtInwardNo').focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
        else {
            //alert('invoice not found');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Throw us a bone: Tell us what `Trim` does, and what the return value is when you do `Trim(ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText)`. (For that latter, I *think* you've said it's `1`, which seems odd if we assume `Trime` is like `String#trim` and returns a string...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Sorry if my code is wrong. It returns me `1` or `0` Yes it returns a string value.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: let me know what is the correct way to do this. and run the second function when it has some value other than 0

Comment: Better convert it to int because returned value is of type string.

Comment: @ADarnal: yes let me know how to convert that to int

Comment: Where do you try to call getOtherDBInward() ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with that code.

1. Until ES2015, it was invalid to *declare* a function inside a flow-control block (like the body of an `if`), and it remains a Really Bad Idea™. But that's what your code is doing.
2. You've *declared* the function, but you haven't called it. So stepping right out is exactly what the debugger should do; there was nothing left to do in `getCounterForCheck`.
3. In comments, you've said `Trim(ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText)` will return `"1"` or `"0"` (e.g., strings). But you're comparing that to `0` (the number). Since you're using loose comparison (`!=`), JavaScript will coerce the value for you, and in this particular case it will do so in the way you're probably expecting. I raise it just because it might make sense for `Trim` to explicitly convert the value and return `1` or `0` (e.g., as numbers).

Declare the function *outside* the `if` block, and call it if you want to call it. Something like:

```
function getCounterForCheck() {
    StrPriFnName = "getCounterForCheckInward(" + document.getElementById('TxtInwardNo').value + ")";
    var ObjPriXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    ObjPriXMLHTTP.open("GET", "FrmInwardXMLHTTP.aspx?para=" + StrPriFnName, false);
    ObjPriXMLHTTP.send("");

    if (Trim(ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText) != 0) {
        getOtherDBInward();
    }
    else {
        //alert('invoice not found');
    }

    function getOtherDBInward() {
        StrPriFnName = "FunGetOTHERDBInward(" + document.getElementById('TxtInwardNo').value + ")";
        var ObjPriXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        ObjPriXMLHTTP.open("GET", "FrmInwardXMLHTTP.aspx?para=" + StrPriFnName, false);
        ObjPriXMLHTTP.send("");

        if (Trim(ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText) != "") {
            var StrPriData = ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText.split('~');
            document.getElementById('HidRefMkey').value = StrPriData[0];
            document.getElementById('TxtDeliveredBy').value = StrPriData[1];
            document.getElementById('cmbRecdDept').value = StrPriData[2];
            FunEmpFillDept();
            document.getElementById('cmbRecdEmp').value = StrPriData[3];
            document.getElementById('HidCurrentEmp').value = StrPriData[3];
            document.getElementById('Txt_RefBillNo').value = StrPriData[6];
            igdrp_getComboById("DtmInfRef_DocDate").setValue(Trim(StrPriData[7]));
            igedit_getById("TxtWN_Billamt").setValue(StrPriData[8]);
            document.getElementById('TxtRemarks').value = StrPriData[9];
            document.getElementById('TxtPartyName').value = StrPriData[10];
        }

        else {
            alert("ERROR: Document does not exist");
            //alert("ERROR: Document does not exist and status also");
            document.getElementById('TxtInwardNo').focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't looked closely at the function, but if it doesn't have to be nested inside `getCounterForCheck`, you might move it out.

Comment: let me try and check

Comment: sir, it is working. but can we convert that `string` into `int` for more accuracy

Comment: @nad: Yes. There are dozens of questions, with answers, about that here on SO.

Comment: @T J: is that correct syntax for converting to int `if (parseInt(ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText) != 0)` ??

Comment: @T J: yes it's correct and it is working for me. Thanks a lot sir.